# Sliding Menu - From Right to left

Tags: android, slidingmenu

I was trying with Sliding menu from the below example.

https://github.com/eddieringle/android-undergarment

But this has the sliding implementation from left to right. How can i change this to Right to left. Can any one please help me to figure this out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i know you get your answer but if you don't want to use any external library you can use this:

this code exist on [gitHub](https://github.com/akotoe/android-slide-out-menu)

but this project use for left right menu, with a little change you can open from right to left, i copy code with changes. with following code you can have both side menu.

**CollapseAnimation.java**

```
import android.view.animation.AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.TranslateAnimation;
import android.widget.FrameLayout.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;


public class CollapseAnimation extends TranslateAnimation implements TranslateAnimation.AnimationListener{

    private LinearLayout slidingLayout;
    int panelWidth;

    public CollapseAnimation(LinearLayout layout, int width, int fromXType, float fromXValue, int toXType,
            float toXValue, int fromYType, float fromYValue, int toYType, float toYValue) {

        super(fromXType, fromXValue, toXType, toXValue, fromYType, fromYValue, toYType, toYValue);

        //Initialize
        slidingLayout = layout;
        panelWidth = width;
        setDuration(400);
        setFillAfter( false );
        setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());
        setAnimationListener(this);

        //Clear left and right margins
        LayoutParams params = (LayoutParams) slidingLayout.getLayoutParams();
        params.rightMargin = 0;
        params.leftMargin = 0;
        slidingLayout.setLayoutParams(params);
        slidingLayout.requestLayout();       
        slidingLayout.startAnimation(this);

    }
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {

    }

    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

    }

    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

    }

}
```

**ExpandAnimation.java**

```
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.animation.AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.TranslateAnimation;
import android.widget.FrameLayout.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class ExpandAnimation extends TranslateAnimation implements Animation.AnimationListener{

    private LinearLayout slidingLayout;
    int panelWidth;

    public ExpandAnimation(LinearLayout layout, int width, int fromXType, float fromXValue, int toXType,
            float toXValue, int fromYType, float fromYValue, int toYType, float toYValue) {

        super(fromXType, fromXValue, toXType, toXValue, fromYType, fromYValue, toYType, toYValue);

        //Initialize
        slidingLayout = layout;
        panelWidth = width;
        setDuration(400);
        setFillAfter( false );
        setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());
        setAnimationListener(this);
        slidingLayout.startAnimation(this);
    }


    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation arg0) {

        //Create margin and align left
        LayoutParams params = (LayoutParams) slidingLayout.getLayoutParams();
        params.rightMargin = panelWidth;
        params.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT;    
        slidingLayout.clearAnimation();
        slidingLayout.setLayoutParams(params);
        slidingLayout.requestLayout();

    }

    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation arg0) {

    }

    public void onAnimationStart(Animation arg0) {

    }

}
```

**LayerStack.java**

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.TranslateAnimation;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class LayerStack extends Activity {

    //Declare
    private LinearLayout slidingPanel;
    private boolean isExpanded;
    private DisplayMetrics metrics; 
    private ListView listView;
    private RelativeLayout headerPanel;
    private RelativeLayout menuPanel;
    private int panelWidth;
    private ImageView menuViewButton;

    FrameLayout.LayoutParams menuPanelParameters;
    FrameLayout.LayoutParams slidingPanelParameters;
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams headerPanelParameters ;
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams listViewParameters;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_layer_stack);

        //Initialize
        metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
        panelWidth = (int) ((metrics.widthPixels)*0.33);

        headerPanel = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.header);
        headerPanelParameters = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) headerPanel.getLayoutParams();
        headerPanelParameters.width = metrics.widthPixels;
        headerPanel.setLayoutParams(headerPanelParameters);

        menuPanel = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.menuPanel);
        menuPanelParameters = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams) menuPanel.getLayoutParams();
        menuPanelParameters.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT;
        menuPanelParameters.width = panelWidth;

        menuPanel.setLayoutParams(menuPanelParameters);

        slidingPanel = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.slidingPanel);
        slidingPanelParameters = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams) slidingPanel.getLayoutParams();
        slidingPanelParameters.width = metrics.widthPixels;
        slidingPanelParameters.gravity = Gravity.LEFT;
        slidingPanel.setLayoutParams(slidingPanelParameters);

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        listViewParameters = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) listView.getLayoutParams();
        listViewParameters.width = metrics.widthPixels;
        listView.setLayoutParams(listViewParameters);


        //Slide the Panel   
        menuViewButton = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.menuViewButton);
        menuViewButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(!isExpanded){
                    isExpanded = true;                                              

                    //Expand
                    new ExpandAnimation(slidingPanel, panelWidth,
                    Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f,
                    Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, -0.33f, 0, 0.0f, 0, 0.0f); 
                     // if you want left to right just remove ( - ) before 0.33f                                        
                }else{
                    isExpanded = false;

                    //Collapse
                    new CollapseAnimation(slidingPanel,panelWidth,
                    TranslateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT,-0.33f,
                    TranslateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f, 0, 0.0f, 0, 0.0f);
                    // if you want left to right just remove ( - ) before 0.33f

                }              
            }
        });

    }       
}
```

**activity_layer_stack.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@drawable/blue_bg">

    <!-- Menu Panel -->
    <RelativeLayout
           android:id="@+id/menuPanel"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:gravity="right"
           android:background="@drawable/gray_bg"
           android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/menu_title_1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="0dp" 
                android:paddingLeft="15dp"             
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:background="#353535"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:text="@string/menu_title">     
            </TextView>

            <View
                android:id="@+id/menu_item_divider_1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="0.5dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/menu_title_1"
                android:background="#b5b5b5"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/menu_item_1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"             
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_below="@+id/menu_item_divider_1"
                android:text="@string/item_1">     
            </TextView>     
             <View
                android:id="@+id/menu_item_divider_2"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="0.5dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/menu_item_1"
                android:background="#b5b5b5"/> 
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/menu_item_2"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/menu_item_divider_2"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:text="@string/item_2">
            </TextView>
            <View
                android:id="@+id/menu_item_divider_3"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="0.5dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/menu_item_2"
                android:background="#b5b5b5" />           
            </RelativeLayout>

       <!-- Sliding Panel -->     
        <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/slidingPanel"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:background="@android:color/white" >

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/header"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/blue_bg" >

                        <View
                            android:id="@+id/header_vertical_divider_1"
                            android:layout_width="2dp"
                            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/menuViewButton"
                            android:background="@drawable/engraved_bg" />

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/menuViewButton"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                            android:clickable="true"
                            android:contentDescription="@string/description"
                            android:src="@drawable/icon_menu"
                            android:visibility="visible" />

                </RelativeLayout>

                <View
                     android:id="@+id/dividerHeaderBottom"
                     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                     android:layout_height="1dp"
                     android:background="#414141" />
                <ListView
                    android:id="@+id/list"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:divider="#b5b5b5"
                    android:dividerHeight="0.5dp"
                    android:background="@android:color/white"
                     >
                </ListView>

        </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu
Try this. It has different modes like from right to left and many other customizations