# SlidingMenu Left and Right - Can you make different sizes?

Tags: android

I am trying to setup dual `slidingmenus` (using the popular one by jfeinstein10).

I want the left slideout to be "shorter" than the right (which should take up 95% of the screen on my app). Normally I use this:

`sMenu.setBehindOffsetRes(R.dimen.slidingmenu_offset)`;

**Simple question:**

But that sets the size for both.  Can I do it separately?

Comment: if you want left and right menu without any library take a look to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14797078/sliding-menu-from-right-to-left/21657527, with this you can do what ever you want with change some variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not without subclassing his sliding menu. You also cannot apply a animation/transformation that is different for either side. It is a frustrating limitation of the library.

Comment: The animation is fine with me to be the same.  Subclassing just means getting two different instances of it then? Maybe `SlidingMenu rMenu` and `SlidingMenu lMenu`, for example, and assigning different value to each?

Comment: I tried doing this:  `lMenu = getSlidingMenu();` and `rMenu = getSlidingMenu();`  It had unintended effects, but would this work to control the two sliders with different parameters?

Comment: The default implementation only has one "BehindView" which contains both the left and the right "views". You would need to subclass the SlidingMenu class and add a new instance variable for an independent left/right offset value.  You would also need to change the CustomViewBehind class to use the second offset. Specifically the onLayout method.

Answer (score 6):

***EDITED:***

Guys, i can see you still vote up this answer, but has been outdated even since Navigation Drawer was released. For now, you can use Material Design guidelines to do this. Just keep yourself in trend, don't be lazy.

**OLD ONE:**

Actually you may use [all_sides](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu/tree/all-sides) branch to do it as well.

for set behind view use

```
getSlidingMenu().setMenu(resID, side)
```

E.G. **BaseActivity**:

```
SlidingMenu sm = getSlidingMenu();
sm.setMenu(R.layout.menu_frame_two, SlidingMode.RIGHT);
sm.setShadowDrawable(R.drawable.shadowright, SlidingMode.RIGHT);
sm.setBehindWidthRes(R.dimen.slidingmenu_width_right, SlidingMode.RIGHT);
sm.setBehindWidthRes(R.dimen.slidingmenu_width_left, SlidingMode.LEFT);
sm.setMode(SlidingMode.LEFT_RIGHT);
```

xml **/values/dimen.xml**:

```
<!-- SlidingMenu right width-->
<dimen name="slidingmenu_width_right">150dp</dimen>
<!-- SlidingMenu left width-->
<dimen name="slidingmenu_width_left">60dp</dimen>
```